# Python AssertionError creating a class

Tags: python

I have a class User, and a class Theme. The user class can create a Theme, add a Theme to the Theme's dictionary, and should be able to return the dictionary of themes. I'm really new to python so I'm having trouble with the python logic/syntax

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.themes = {}

    def createTheme(self, name, themeType, numWorkouts, themeID, timesUsed):
        newTheme = Theme(name, themeType, numWorkouts, themeID, timesUsed)
        return newTheme
```

and my Theme class:

```
class Theme:
    def __init__(self, name, themeType, numWorkouts, themeID, timesUsed):
        #themeType: 1 = genre, 2 = artist, 3 = song
        self.name = name
        self.themeType = themeType
        self.numWorkouts = numWorkouts
        self.themeID = themeID
        self.timesUsed = timesUsed
```

I run the test in testUser:

```
## test createTheme
    theme1 = Theme("theme", 2, 5, 1, 0)
    self.assertEqual(usr1.createTheme("theme", 2, 5, 1, 0), theme1)
```

but I get - 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Tests/testUser.py", line 52, in test
    self.assertEqual(usr1.createTheme("theme", 2, 5, 1, 0), theme1)
AssertionError:  !=

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, can anyone please help?

(Also, I have the following methods in User, but haven't been able to test them yet since my createTheme doesn't work, but I could use some help to see if there are errors in my logic/syntax:

```
# returns dict
# def getThemes(self):
#     return self.themes
#
# def addTheme(self, themeID, theme):
#     if theme not in self.themes:
#         themes[themeID] = theme
#
# def removeTheme(self, _theme):
#     if _theme.timesUsed == _theme.numWorkouts:
#         del themes[_theme.themeID]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What is happening

When attempting to determine if two objects are equal, say `obj1 == obj2`, Python will do the following.

1. It will first attempt to call `obj1.__eq__(obj2)`, that is a method
   defined in the class of `obj1` which should determine the logic for
   equality.
2. If this method does not exist, or return `NotImplemented`, then
   Python falls back on calling `obj2.__eq__(obj1)`.
3. If this is still not conclusive, Python will return `id(obj1) == id(obj2)`, 
    i.e. it will tell you if both values are the same object in memory.

In your test, Python has to fall back to the third option and your object are two different instances of the class `Theme`.

### What you want to happen

If you expect objects `Theme("theme", 2, 5, 1, 0)` and `usr1.createTheme("theme", 2, 5, 1, 0)` to be equal because they have the same attributes, you have to define the `Theme.__eq__` method like so.

```
class Theme:
    def __init__(self, name, themeType, numWorkouts, themeID, timesUsed):
        #themeType: 1 = genre, 2 = artist, 3 = song
        self.name = name
        self.themeType = themeType
        self.numWorkouts = numWorkouts
        self.themeID = themeID
        self.timesUsed = timesUsed

    def __eq__(self, other)
        # You can implement the logic for equality here
        return (self.name, self.themeType, self.numWorkouts, self.themeID) ==\
               (other.name, other.themeType, other.numWorkouts, other.themeID)
```

Note that I am wrapping the attributes in tuples and I then compare the tuples for readability, but you could also compare attributes one by one.

Comment: How should I test the createTheme method correctly and compare it to a correct result?

Comment: Your test returns the correct answer. It is your method that seems to be wrong, so it's a good test. What is the behaviour you want exactly?

Comment: I would like createTheme to just create a new Theme based on the inputs

Comment: It is what it does. You test does not fail because a new instance wasn't created. It fails exactly because a new instance was created. Actually, why did you expect your test to be true, the object are NOT equal?

Comment: Sorry - I just saw I had a typo in my test but I made them the same (both named just "theme", not "Beyonce theme", but I get the same error

Comment: I now understand what you need. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @Olivier, do I replace the self.assertEqual method with self.__eq__?

Comment: No, only add the `__eq__` method provided above in your `Theme` class. Do not touch the `assertTrue`, Python will recognize that it must use `__eq__` to compare both objects in `assertTrue`. You should never call a magic method, that is what we call method with `__*__` around theme yourself unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Oh shoot I've run into another error when testing my addTheme method :( - when I try to do usr1.addTheme(theme1) in my test cases, it says TypeError: addTheme() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given - could you also help me with this error?

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question. Stackoverflow is not only a plateform to help users, but only to gather and organize answers for future use. Thus creating another question would be the correct practice. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome answer man, very descriptive, you could add interpreter session of proving the concept although it's not needed. :)